# snapshot.data returing null in Flutter. Using in Translator package

Tags: flutter, null

I am using [translator](https://pub.dev/packages/translator) package for automatically translate the String value in the Text widget, but my codes are not working.. just returning **null**.

**Codes:**

```
Future<String> translate(String input, String to) async {
    final translator = GoogleTranslator();
    var translation = await translator.translate(input, from: 'en', to: to);
    return translation.text;
  }
```

---

```
class TranslatedText extends StatefulWidget {
  String data;
  String to;
  TranslatedText({Key? key, required this.data, required this.to}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TranslatedText> createState() => _TranslatedTextState();
}

class _TranslatedTextState extends State<TranslatedText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: MainController().translate(widget.data, widget.to),
        builder: (BuildContext c, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          return Text('${snapshot.data}');
        });
  }
}
```

---

```
TranslatedText(data: "Egg", to: "es"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common behavior for FutureBuilder. It resolves in the future and returns a response (snapshot) after a while, so you need to check the snapshot first and structure your code accordingly. Like:

```dart
  FutureBuilder(
      future: MainController().translate(widget.data, widget.to),
      builder: (BuildContext c, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var result = snapshot.data as String;
            return Text(result);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('An error occurred');
          } else {
            return Text('No data returned from API');
          }
        }
      });
```

[FutureBuilder doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)